# Finding the value of a continued fraction?

Tags: continued-fractions

I know how to calculate the exact value for continued fractions such as

$$1+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{\ddots}}}=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

However, is it possible to find the value of continued fraction

$$1+\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{6+\cfrac{1}{24+\cfrac{1}{\ddots}}}}$$

($[1!;2!,3!,4!,5!,6!,\dots]$)

Thanks!

Comment: Certainly this continued fraction will converge very quickly to its limit; you should try writing a short program to compute the first 30 or so convergents. If you are asking whether this continued fraction has a "nice" expression, the answer is that it depends on what you mean by "nice." Continued fractions may not represent algebraic numbers like the first example; $\pi$ and $e$ have well-known and quite regular continued fraction representations, but both are transcendental numbers.

Comment: Algebraic numbers have convergents (the truncations of the continued fractions) converging 'rather slowly' to the limit. This is likely to not be an algebraic number, i.e. it will be transcendental.

Comment: @proximal the continued fractions of $\pi$ and $e$ don't seem to be quite regular. You may be thinking of other expressions looking similar to continued fractions.

Comment: @franklin.vp $e$ apparently has a regular pattern, in the sense that it goes $1,n+2,1$ in the 'repeated' part.  So it starts $[2,1,2,1,1,4,1,1,6,1,1,8,1]$.  In any case, it converges after 8! to $1.461 783 355 000 579 602 560 079 367 397$

Comment: In general, if you truncate $\beta = [a_0; a_1, a_2\ldots]$ to a finite fraction $[a_0; a_1, \ldots, a_n]$ you get a good rational approximation to $\beta$, and the quality of the approximation is better if the remaining $a_i$ are larger integers. For example, the excellence of the approximation $\pi \approx\frac{355}{133}$ is directly related to the fact that it is the truncation of $\pi$'s continued fraction $[3; 7, 15, 1, 292, 1,1,1]$ just after the suprisingly large integer 292. Your fraction has even larger partial denominators, so it is easy to find a good rational approximation to it.

Comment: See [OEIS A$100608$](http://oeis.org/A100608).

Answer (score 1):

It converges, but not to anything particular at all.

Take a look at [this](http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1.4617833550005)